# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

How do I clear the gradient before calling the `.backward()` for the second time.

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify `retain_graph=True` when calling backward the first time.

```
a = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad = True)
b = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad = True)
d = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad = True)
c=a*b
c.backward()
e = d*e
e.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

I tried doing this: `c.zero_grad()` but I got the error `c` has no method `zero_grad()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message reads, you need to specify the `retain_graph=True` option on the first `.backward` call, not the second:

```
c.backward(retain_graph=True)
e = d*c
e.backward()
```

If you do not retain the graph, the second backward pass will not be able to reach the nodes `c`, `a`, and `b` because the activations will have been cleared by the first backward pass.

Comment: Thanks.. now understand it better